# Generating graphs of groups

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, graph-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group and $S \subset G$ is its finite subset. Let’s define the *generating graph* of $G$ in respect to $S$ as $Gen(G, S)$ - a graph $\Gamma(V, E)$, where $V = S$ and $E = \{(a, b) \in S \times S | a \neq b \text{ and } \langle \{a, b\} \rangle = G\}$.

Let’s define the *generating graph representation number* as the minimal number $GGRN(n)$, such that any $n$-vertex graph is isomorphic to a commuting subgraph of some group of order $GGRN(n)$.

My question is:

> Is there some exact formula (or at least asymptotic) for $GGRN(n)$?

The only thing that I managed to prove, was the following bound:

$$GGRN(n) \leq p_{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\#$$

Here $p_n\#$ stands for [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial)

Indeed, for any $n$ vertex graph $\Gamma(V, E)$, where $V = \{1, 2, … n\}$ such group and the corresponding subset can be explicitly constructed as

$$G = \langle a \rangle_{p_{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\#} $$
$$S = \{a^{f(v)\Pi_{(v, u) \in E}f((v, u))}| v \in V\}$$

where $f$ is some bijection from $V \cup V \times V$ onto first $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ primes.

However, this upper bound seems to be too large to be the best one: as the primorial has the asymptotic $p_n\# = e^{(1 + o(1))nlog(n)}$, then our bound is asymptotically $e^{(1 + o(1))n^2log(n)}$. Quite large, isn't it? Thus there is very likely to be something better. Much better. However, I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: I believe your formula for $S$ should say $(v,u)\notin E$. You can eke out some minor improvement as follows: if you have an independent set, you can cover all the missing edges in that set with one prime. Thus (switching from independent sets to cliques), you need to know the maximum number of cliques needed to cover the edges a graph on $n$ vertices. That is less than $n(n-1)/2$, but at best by a constant factor (as the example $K_{n/2,n/2}$ shows).

Comment: When you crosspost, you should acknowledge it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3397187/generating-graphs-of-groups